# Why is my UserId returning a Username resulting in conversion error?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-4, asp.net-identity, asp.net-roles

I'm following this tutorial http://tutlane.com/tutorial/aspnet-mvc/asp-net-mvc-membership-provider-to-create-users-roles-mapping-roles-to-users.

When I try to add a role, I get the following error:

```
Input string was not in a correct format.
```

at this line

```
var User = GetUserName_BY_UserID(Convert.ToInt32(objvm.UserId));
```

I think the problem is that UserId is returning the Username and not the UserId, but I don't know what I did wrong to be getting the Username.

**AccountController**
*RoleAddToUser*

```
  [HttpGet]
        public ActionResult RoleAddToUser()
        {
            AssignRoleVM objvm = new AssignRoleVM(); //http://tutlane.com/tutorial/aspnet-mvc/asp-net-mvc-membership-provider-to-create-users-roles-mapping-roles-to-users
            objvm.RolesList = GetAll_Roles();
            objvm.Userlist = GetAll_Users();
            return View(objvm);
        }

   [HttpPost]
        [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
        public ActionResult RoleAddToUser(AssignRoleVM objvm)
        {
            //Validation inside RoleAddtoUser ActionMethod: First validation to check both dropdownlist are select or not.
            if (objvm.RoleName == "0")
            {
                ModelState.AddModelError("RoleName", "Please select RoleName");
            }
            if (objvm.UserId == "0")
            {
                ModelState.AddModelError("UserName", "Please select Username");
            }
            if (ModelState.IsValid)
            {
                GetUserName_BY_UserID(Convert.ToInt32(objvm.UserId));
                var User = GetUserName_BY_UserID(Convert.ToInt32(objvm.UserId));
                Roles.AddUserToRole(User, objvm.RoleName);
                ViewBag.ResultMessage = "Username added to the role successfully !";

                objvm.RolesList = GetAll_Roles();
                objvm.Userlist = GetAll_Users();
                return View(objvm);
            }
            else
            {
                objvm.RolesList = GetAll_Roles();
                objvm.Userlist = GetAll_Users();
            }
            return View(objvm);
        }
```

**AccountController**
*GetUserName_BY_UserID*

```
public string GetUserName_BY_UserID(int UserId)
{
    using (UsersContext context = new UsersContext())
    {
        var UserName = (from UP in context.UserProfiles
                        where UP.UserId == UserId
                        select UP.UserName).SingleOrDefault();
        return UserName;
    }
}
```

**Models**
*AccountModel.cs*

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations;
using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations.Schema;
using System.Data.Entity;
using System.Globalization;
using System.Web.Security;

namespace AccountModule_Attempt_5.Models
{
    public class UsersContext : DbContext
    {
        public UsersContext()
            : base("DefaultConnection")
        {
        }

        public DbSet<UserProfile> UserProfiles { get; set; }
        public DbSet<Customer> Customers { get; set; }
        public DbSet<Role> Roles { get; set; }
        public DbSet<webpages_UsersInRoles> webpages_UsersInRole { get; set; }
       // public DbSet<RegisterModel> UserProfiles { get; set; }
        //public DbSet<RegisterModel>Users { get; set; }
       // public DbSet<UsersRole> UsersRoles { get; set; }   
    }

    [Table("webpages_UsersInRoles")]
    public class webpages_UsersInRoles
    {
        [Key]
        [DatabaseGeneratedAttribute(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]
        public int UserId { get; set; }

        public int RoleId { get; set; }
    }
```

*AssignRoleVM.cs*

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Web.Mvc;

namespace AccountModule_Attempt_5.Models
{
    public class AssignRoleVM
    {

        [Required(ErrorMessage = " Select Role Name")]
        public string RoleName { get; set; }
        [Required(ErrorMessage = "Select UserName")]
        public string UserId { get; set; }

        public List<SelectListItem> Userlist { get; set; }
        public List<SelectListItem> RolesList { get; set; }
    }
}
```

*UserProfile.cs*

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations;
using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations.Schema;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;

namespace AccountModule_Attempt_5.Models
{
    [Table("UserProfile")]
    public class UserProfile
    {
        [Key]
        [DatabaseGeneratedAttribute(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]
        public int UserId { get; set; }

        [Required]
        public string UserName { get; set; }
        public string EmailId { get; set; }

        [Required]       
        public string CustomerId { get; set; }

    }

}
```

*Roles.cs*

```
using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations;
using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations.Schema;

namespace AccountModule_Attempt_5.Models
{

    [Table("webpages_Roles")]
    public class Role
    {
        [Required(ErrorMessage = "Enter Role name")]
        //[StringLength(100, ErrorMessage = "The {0} must be at least {2} characters long.", MinimumLength = 6)]
        public string RoleName { get; set; }

        [Key]
        [DatabaseGeneratedAttribute(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]
        public int RoleId { get; set; }
    }
}
```

Comment: *"I think the problem is that UserId is returning the Username and not the UserId"*: Why do you think that? Why aren't you certain, one way or the other?

Comment: As a sidenote, the '_' in your naming convention might ruffle some feathers in a real-world, work environment (making lots of assumptions here, sorry :) )

Comment: Well, I know that it is returning the Username because when I try to add the role, I can see the Username as I hover over objvm.UserId in the RoleAddToUser Method as opposed to the UserId. What I don't know is if that is the problem because I'm still pretty new at this.

Comment: @JoshMcGee - You're converting your user ID to an int; ASP.Net Identity typically uses GUID for the UserID - so try using Guid and not int instead. - check your database first though, for the UserID type or hover over your objvm.UserID property in debug and see what it actually looks like.

Comment: @Darren where do I add this code? I tried replacing Convert.ToInt32(objvm.UserId), but got an Argument1: cannot convert from "System.Guid to 'int' and if I replace the entire variable with this, it causes  "System.Guid to 'string' in the next line.

Answer (score 0):

The main reason for the problem is because you're trying to convert a string variable (that is not numeric) to to Int32.  In order for the UserId to be converted to Int 32, it should be numeric.

Also, the userID shouldn't be mixed with other characters other than numeric.

For example if the userID is "101" it will be converted with no problem.  But a userID "Zbra101" cannot be converted to Int 32.

Comment: Thank you. That is my problem. The UserId should be numbers. Why is it returning the Username? When I look in my UserProfile table I have UserId and UserName. I would think this should return UserId.

Answer (score 0):

you can try these.
Add Changes in AccountController.

```
[HttpGet]
 public ActionResult RoleAddToUser()
{
        AssignRoleVM objvm = new AssignRoleVM(); 
        objvm.RolesList = GetAll_Roles();
        objvm.Userlist = GetAll_Users();
        return View(objvm);
}

   [HttpPost]
    [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
    public ActionResult RoleAddToUser(AssignRoleVM objvm)
    {

        if (objvm.RoleName == "0")
        {
            ModelState.AddModelError("RoleName", "Please select RoleName");
        }
        if (objvm.UserId == "0")
        {
            ModelState.AddModelError("UserName", "Please select Username");
        }
        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {

            var User = objvm.UserId;
            Roles.AddUserToRole(User, objvm.RoleName);
            ViewBag.ResultMessage = "Username added to the role successfully !";

            objvm.RolesList = GetAll_Roles();
            objvm.Userlist = GetAll_Users();
            return View(objvm);
        }
        else
        {
            objvm.RolesList = GetAll_Roles();
            objvm.Userlist = GetAll_Users();
        }
        return View(objvm);
    }
```